# frame shows black screen

Tags: java, swing, listener, concurrency

```
btnnew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Hello");
                packetListener.listener();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

I get a black screen when it runs. But when the `packetListener.listener();` calls in the constructor it shows.

Can you please explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `packetListener.listener();` method performs some complex operation which blocks your UI.

Better create a thread for listening the packet.
ie,use it like this

```
 try {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
packetListener.listener();
            }
    }).start();         

        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: @user1089146, I gave you this answer over a week ago. The tutorial explains your exact problem explaining why you need to use a separate Thread. It even gives a working solution using a SwingWorker which creates the Thread for you making the code easier.

Answer (score 3):

Code that is executed from a listener executes on the EDT. I'm guessing that the packetListner.listener() method blocks in which case the GUI will freeze. You should not be blocking the EDT.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for a full description of this problem and a solution.